# ContextErrorException Notice: Undefined index: product in ps_sharebuttons.php line 138

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

i have this error in my prestashop 1.7 project when i enable mode degub:
ContextErrorException Notice: Undefined index: product in ps_sharebuttons.php line 138.

the line 138 looks like :

$key = 'ps_sharebuttons|' . $params['product']['id_product'];

full code:

```
public function renderWidget($hookName, array $params)
{
    $key = 'ps_sharebuttons|' . $params['product']['id_product'];
    if (!empty($params['product']['id_product_attribute'])) {
        $key .= '|' . $params['product']['id_product_attribute'];
    }

    if (!$this->isCached($this->templateFile, $this->getCacheId($key))) {
        $this->smarty->assign($this->getWidgetVariables($hookName, $params));
    }
```

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this seems an issue with the **ps_sharebuttons** module, check for an up-to-date version, maybe ?

If you just want get rid of the warning, just modify the code as follow :

```
public function renderWidget($hookName, array $params)
{
    if (isset($params['product'])) {
        $key = 'ps_sharebuttons|' . $params['product']['id_product'];
        rest of the code here ...
   }
```